# about toolStripDropDownButton

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip, toolstripdropdown

I have a form. I've added the strip down button using drag and drop in the form. How can I (in the program) create and fill the toolStripMenu Item? My menu could contain different element...with different names.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add items programmatically to a `ToolStripDropDownButton` just do:

```
var item1 = new ToolStripButton("my button");
toolStripDropDownButton1.DropDownItems.Add(item1);

var item2 = new ToolStripComboBox("my combo");
toolStripDropDownButton1.DropDownItems.Add(item2);

// etc ...
```

---

Instead, if you need to add other `ToolStripDropDownButton` or other elements directly to you menu (`ToolStrip`), just do:

```
var item1 = new ToolStripDropDownButton("my dropdown button");
toolStrip1.Items.Add(item1);

var item2 = new ToolStripProgressBar("my progress bar");
toolStrip1.Items.Add(item2);

// etc ...
```

---

**EDIT:**

You must do it after `InitializeComponent()` otherwise you won't be able to access to design-time added components, e.g.:

```
InitializeComponent();

// we're after InitializeComponent...
// let's add 10 buttons under "toolStripDropDownButton1" ...
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var item = new ToolStripButton("Button_"+i);
    toolStripDropDownButton1.DropDownItems.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: how can i do it in a loop?..THX

Comment: Basically, add it where you need it. Just add it after `InitializeComponents` otherwise you couldn't access to design-time added components...

Comment: ok..i've added it in the toolStripDropDownButton -> the method that actually appear when you double click the button from the form. Now i have an warning saying that he method System.Windows.Forms.Form.toolStrripDropButton can't be found. I've set the method public ..and i have the same error. WHY?(thx)

Comment: i'm calling the mthod from initialize component method. It is ok?

Comment: @mike: The 1st method isn't good because it's a click event handler, InitializeComponent isn't good as well because is designer-generated code...
BTW, according to what you said, I think you need more knowledge about WinForms' basis. Look at this good [MSDN Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/360kwx3z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) then ask again if you have problems...

Answer (score 0):

For the [`DropDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownitem.dropdown.aspx) property you need a [`ContextMenuStrip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.aspx). The easiest way to find out how to fill it up is to drag&drop one from the toolbox onto your form, fill it up, select it in the `DropDown` property and afterwards take a look into the Designer.cs file to see how all the stuff is glued together.

The drawback of using the `DropDownItems` property is that you can't alter some properties like [`ShowImageMargin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownmenu.showimagemargin.aspx).